# How can i get the table headers if they are not all text with python and beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

**Hi guys,**

I am basically new to coding in general so bare with me.

**I am trying to retrieve the table headers for this table:**
https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/manchester-united-fc/leistungsdaten/verein/985/reldata/%262022/plus/1

[image]

First i tried with pandas but i could not get my data so i learned about beautifull soup and tried my luck with it.

The problem is that some headers are text and i could get the info pretty easily using this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/manchester-united-fc/leistungsdaten/verein/985/reldata/%262022/plus/1'

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

response.content

soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')

soup.prettify().splitlines()

tabela_equipa = soup.find('table', {'class': 'items'} )

headers_tabela = [th.text.encode("utf-8") for th in tabela_equipa.select("tr th")]

print(headers_tabela)
```

Output:
[b'#', b'player', b'Age', b'Nat.', b'In squad', b'\xc2\xa0', b'\xc2\xa0', b'\xc2\xa0', b'\xc2\xa0', b'\xc2\xa0', b'\xc2\xa0', b'\xc2\xa0', b'\xc2\xa0', b'PPG', b'\xc2\xa0']

The thing is that most of those headers are icons and the info i need is actually in the span title, and there is where my problem resides, because i am not being able to find anywhere how to get all that info in order to build my table headers so then i can scrape the rest of the table.

[image]

Anyone knows a way of doing it?
been trying for 4 days without success before posting here.

Then i tried to get all the spans using this code:

```
thead = soup.thead
Theaders = thead.find_all('span')
print(Theaders)
```

Output:

```
[<span class="icons_sprite icon-einsaetze-table-header sort-link-icon" title="Appearances"> </span>, <span class="icons_sprite icon-tor-table-header sort-link-icon" title="Goals"> </span>, <span class="icons_sprite icon-vorlage-table-header sort-link-icon" title="Assists"> </span>, <span class="icons_sprite icon-gelbekarte-table-header sort-link-icon" title="Yellow cards"> </span>, <span class="icons_sprite icon-gelbrotekarte-table-header sort-link-icon" title="Second yellow cards"> </span>, <span class="icons_sprite icon-rotekarte-table-header sort-link-icon" title="Red cards"> </span>, <span class="icons_sprite icon-einwechslungen-table-header sort-link-icon" title="Substitutions on"> </span>, <span class="icons_sprite icon-auswechslungen-table-header sort-link-icon" title="Substitutions off"> </span>, <span class="icons_sprite icon-minuten-table-header sort-link-icon" title="Minutes played"> </span>]
```

Getting close i thought as i could see all the info i needed was there.
But then i hit the wall, i can get one span title but not all in a list:

thead = soup.thead
Theaders = thead.find('span')['title']
print(Theaders)

Output:
Appearances

```
thead = soup.thead
Theaders = thead.find_all('span')['title']
print(Theaders)
```

Output:

```
---> 23 Theaders = thead.find_all('span')['title']
     24 print(Theaders)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

and even then i will run into the problem of it not being in the same order as it was on the original table.

Maybe i am just being dumb but any help would be much aprecciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/manchester-united-fc/leistungsdaten/verein/985/reldata/%262022/plus/1'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

html_headers = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'sort-link'})

headers_list = []
for i in html_headers:
    if i.find('span') == None:
        headers_list.append(i.get_text())
    else:
        headers_list.append(i.find('span')['title'])

print(headers_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this one. now it seems simple after i see your solution but it wa driving me crazy not finding this anywhere else. This is the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can get what's missing from

```py
>>> [span.get_attribute_list("title")[0] for span in thead.find_all('span')]
['Appearances',
 'Goals',
 'Assists',
 'Yellow cards',
 'Second yellow cards',
 'Red cards',
 'Substitutions on',
 'Substitutions off',
 'Minutes played']
```

And then manually link those results with what you previously had at `headers_tabela`.

However, for consistency, I recommend fetching them one by one:

```py
def anchor_span(th):
    try:
        return th.a.span.get_attribute_list("title")[0]
    except Exception as exc:
        #print(exc)
        return False

def th_text(th):
    try:
        return th.text
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
        return False

def anchor_text(th):
    try:
        ch = th.a.children
        assert len([*ch])==1
        return th.a.text
    except Exception as exc:
        #print(exc)
        return False

def get_col_names(soup):
    colnames = []
    for colnum, th in enumerate(soup.thead.tr.children):
        if isinstance (th, bs4.element.NavigableString):
            continue
    
        title = anchor_span(th)
        if not title:
            title = anchor_text(th)
        if not title:
            title = th_text(th)
        if not title:
            raise NotImplementedError

        colnames.append(title)

table_MN = pd.read_html(response.content, flavor='html5lib')
data = table_MN[1].iloc[:,:15]
data.columns = get_col_names(soup)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! there was a second answer and more simpler solution above that i think for now i am going to use. But i will for sure try to understand everything you wrote because it will be helpfull in the future for sure